Error getting sequence number to auto increment Number field
I am trying to create an Order submission Controller but I want to add a sequence to the order_id field. When I try to run the getNextSequence function from the controller it returns a null value and my api call throws the below error:
"message": "Order validation failed: order_id: Please Enter Order Id"

Below is my Counter model Code:
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var counterSchema = new Schema({
  seq: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter Seq No"],
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Counter", counterSchema);

Below is my function:
const Counter = require("../models/counterModel");

const getNextSequence = (name) => {
  var ret = Counter.findOneAndUpdate({
    query: { _id: name },
    update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
    new: true,
  });
  return ret.seq;
};
module.exports = getNextSequence;

Below is my Controller code to create a new order:
exports.createOrder = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  let nextOrderId = getNextSequence("order_id");
  const newreq = {
    order_id: nextOrderId,
    status: req.body.status,
    stage: req.body.stage,
  };

  console.log(newreq);

  const order = await Order.create(newreq);
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    order,
  });
});

When I console.log(newreq) it shows like this:
{ order_id: undefined, status: 'preparing', stage: 'in oven' }

Somehow the function is not passing order_id sequence number e.g. 3,4,5 to Controller.
Tried to find root cause of issue but not successful.

You have seq defined as a String but you need it to be a Number. Your getNextSequence function needs to be async and then you need to await the findOneAndUpdate. You would then also need to await the getNextSequence call. Your query for the findOneAndUpdate is not constructed properly and options are in the wrong place. Can you share your full schema please?
